# C# How to read items into an array

Tags: c#, arrays

I can't figure out how can I read items from the text file and put them into an int array. My objective is to count what is the average grade. To do so, I need to read the number which tells me how many grades does 1 student have, and then using that amount, read the grades themselves. For example, first column shows the amount of the grades, all remaining columns shows grades:

`5;8;7;9;10;4
3;8;9;10
2;5;9`

The code I wrote:

```
        static void ReadData(out Student[] Student, out Faculty Faculty)
    {
        using (StreamReader read = new StreamReader(@"Data", Encoding.GetEncoding(1257)))
        {
            string line = null;
            Student = new Student[Faculty.CMax];
            Faculty = new Faculty();
            while (null != (line = read.ReadLine()))
            {
                string[] values = line.Split(';');
                string lastname = values[0];
                string name = values[1];
                string group = values[2];
                int amount = int.Parse(values[3]);
                int grades = int.Parse(values[4]);
                Student studen = new Student(lastname, name, group, amount, grades);
                Student.Take[Faculty.AmountOfStudents++] = studen;
            }
        }
    }
```

I know that `int[] grades = int.Parse(values[4]);` is the problem. But I don't know how to fix it. Probably a newbie problem, thanks for the help.

Comment: you are assigning integer to array. should be `int grades = int.Parse(values[4]);`
But you should explain your values better, I don't get what `line` represents .

Comment: How do you know `int[] grades = int.Parse(values[4]);` is the problem? Do you get an exception on that line?

Comment: Row one has 6 items so you can index from 0 to 5.  Row two has four items so you can index from 0 to 3.  Row three has three items so you can index from 0 to 2.  values[4] will only work on first row.  Why are the rows different sizes?

Comment: Seems like homework season has started http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39902014/c-sharp-cannot-read-arrays-from-file

Comment: Link is not working, not really homework, but even if it would be, don't know what's so bad, not like I'm asking for a full code

Comment: @Domzaza Link is working, but you don't have enough reps to see it :) (It is deleted by owner *Julius* and is like this: *"i can't read the arrays from text file here is how it goes: Stud Name, Last Name, Group, number of grades and then grades. text file ........."*)

Answer (score 3):

After your clarification, it seems that you want to take:

```
Smith;John;XYZ;4;2;4;6;8
```

And retrieve the array of `[2,4,6,8]` so you can get the average from that.

If you can't do what I mention in my comment, then here's a workaround. Since the number of grades is irrelevant, just ignore it, and you'll recognize that you need an int array which contains 4 fewer items than the original. Then it's just a matter of copying them:

```
string[] fields = val.Split(';');
int[] grades = new int[fields.Length - 4];
for (int i = 4; i < fields.Length; ++i)
{
    grades[i - 4] = int.Parse(fields[i]);
}
```

Or some other alternate versions if you're into LINQ:

```
string[] fields = val.Split(';');
int[] grades = Enumerable.Range(4, fields.Length - 4)
    .Select(i => int.Parse(fields[i]))
    .ToArray();

string[] fields = val.Split(';');
int[] grades = fields.Select((s, i) => new { s, i })
    .Where(x => x.i >= 4)
    .Select(x => int.Parse(x.s))
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm bad at explaining, My objective is to count what is the average grade. To do so, I need to read the number which tells me how many grades does 1 student have, and then using that amount, read the grades themselves.

Comment: So your data looks like `Smith;John;XYZ;4;2;4;6;8` where 4 is how many grades will follow? That's a ridiculous data format first of all, so I'd try to get that resolved into something a little more useful. The "number of grades" is meaningless because the grades are already there, so you can count them instead of being told how many there are. And if you really want this type of data, you should use a different separator for grades, like `Smith;John;XYZ;2|4|6|8`, so you can split by semi-colon, then split `fields[3]` by pipe.

Comment: @Domzaza Please update your question with with the clarifications you've  made in comments.